# Signal gets amplified in oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, passive-networks

I am fresher and doing a semi-conductor experiment at my university. I have some problems with my oscilloscope.

Signal from my university's oscilloscope:

[image: Signal got from my University's oscilloscope]

My input signal is 2V peak to peak, with the schematic below (capacitor measured by VOM).

[image: Schematic]

The oscilloscope amplified my input signal to 10x. How do we fix it? The oscilloscope is a Tektronix, 2 channels, 100MHz.

Comment: The scope thinks you're using a 10X probe. Set the "Probe" parameter to 1X on each channel.

Comment: ...or toggle the 10x-switch on the probe

Comment: First thing you should do when turning on a scope is configuring your probes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to use the oscilloscope myself because the teacher didn't guide us.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Set the channel to 10x and set the scope probe to 10x. They should always match.

It's almost always better to use 10x because the bandwidth will be better. The input-referred noise will be more however.